# Different between re.match and Path.match

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re, pathlib

I have a list of paths with files name.
The file's name can be random.

I tried using re module with regex tested using online tools. But it return none. Using pathlib.Path.match return what I wanted.

```
l = ["C:/dir/1.png", "C:/dir/a2.png", "C:/dir/2a.png", "C:/dir/a.txt", "C:/dir/x4-444.exe"]
    
pat = re.compile(r"\.png$")

for p in l:
    print("re" ,re.match(pat, p)) # none none none none none
    print("Path", pathlib.Path(p).match("*.png")) # true true true false false
```

I read that re.match() only return what it found at the start of the string, which isn't the case here. How can I use re module in this case? Or should I just stick with Path.match?

Comment: Use `re.search()`, not `re.match()`

Comment: regex is used for far more than paths

Comment: Or change the regexp to `r".*\.png$"`